# GeoIP: Redirect all but specific countries

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond, geoip

I am using Apache's GeoIP module and a MaxMind database to determine the country of a visitor based on their IP address and redirecting them to a country sub-folder as shown below:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/us$1 [L]
```

I would like to redirect all countries to the /us sub-folder except China and Russia. A list of country codes are listed [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/), but I'll prefer to apply a wildcard to the rewrite condition as opposed to listing every country in my `.htaccess` file.

Is it possible to do something like `RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^*$`? Or do I have to expand the rewrite condition with all countries like `RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(US|CA|ZA|NG|GH|)$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use negation `!` to redirect anything but China `CN` and Russia `RU`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(CN|RU)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/us/$1 [L]
```